# Web based application for comparasion of 2 pdf documents

Tags: java, pdf, web-applications, document

We need to integrate into an existing java web application, a new feature that allows the user to compare 2 pdf documents and see the differences. So, I started to search for some already exiting library or tool (open source or commercial) that could help me solve this request.
Does anyone know if exists this kind of application? That would take 2 pdf, compare them and display the differences?

Thanks in advance,
Madalina

Comment: Such tools do exist - the question is what exactly you mean by differences. Do you want to know if the text is different? If the formatting of the text is different? If an element (text or image) is at a different place? If a pixel in an image is different? There are different approaches possible for each such case.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not be satisfactory , but this project from apache -> 
http://pdfbox.apache.org/

may help u. You can convert the pdf's to text file and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i made a PDF comparision project built on PDFBOX you can donwload source code from [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B09BIsDTY_AuV25yaWRNTk5wdHc/view?usp=sharing)

Example Usage is mentioned below it performs three levels of comparison you can simply add a loop by saving target and source files name in a list and then calling its comparison functionalities .

```
        pdfComparison cmp=new pdfComparison();
      //Text Comparision page by page         if(cmp.textComparision("ReferencePDF\\PDF2_302.pdf","C:\\\PDF2_305.pdf"))
              {
        System.out.print("\n********PDF text is identical******* ");

              }
              else 
              {
                  System.out.print("\n********PDF text is  not identical******* ");

              }

//Extract all images in PDF and compare   
    cmp.extract_ALL_Images_ThenCompare("PDF2_302.pdf","PDF2_302.pdf");

//Convert Both PDF pages into JPG and perform image comparison 
        cmp.PDF_Convert_To_Jpeg_Comparision("PDF2_302.pdf","PDF2_302.pdf");
```

You will see all image differences in folder Differences in the project . If any issue just put a message for me

Comment: Your project uses the current PDFBox release 1.8.9. PDFBox releases before version 2 are known to have many deficits when rendering PDF pages as images which have been fixed in the current 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Thus, basing PDF comparisons on PDFBox 1.8.9 might work as a first smoke test or in very controlled environments with PDFs which PDFBox 1.8.9 can properly render, but not in production code for generic PDFs.

Comment: i am not doing comparison using PDF box i am just extracting content by PDF box . Kindly download code first and check it your self .

Comment: Its working fine in my frame work infact i compared 300 pages PDF

Comment: *i am not doing comparison using PDF box* -  In `comparePDF.convertPDFToJPG` you do `page.convertToImage()`; this method calls the code with "many deficits when rendering PDF pages as images". *Kindly download code first and check it your self* - I did so and as a result wrote my initial comment.

Comment: There indeed are many situations in which pdfbox 1.x page rendering works. It's merely risky to use it for generic pdfs.