# How to Compare huge volume of pdf files and get the unique set of files using java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need an API which helps to process huge volume of pdf files, say some 100's to 1000's and then the pdf files needs to grouped in a manner such that unique type of files should be grouped in separate folders.

I have knowledge with pdflib.

Could any body help me?

Comment: What is this 'type' according to which unicity is established?

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson I am not getting you?

Comment: Do you mean, reading a whole bunch of PDF files, somehow finding out what type they are, and then putting "resumes" in one dir, "payment receipts" in another, etc. ?

Comment: @OlivierCroisier Exactly the same.

Comment: I'd go for calculating a simple file hash then. For each file, calculate its MD5 hash, then maintain a Map where the key is the hash, and the value is the list of all files that have that hash. Then, when all files are processed, for every key in the map, create a directory and copy or move there all the related files.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierCroisier I  will try this post the result.

Answer (score 0):

I answered same question in this post have a look if you have any questions you can leave it in comments : [Web based application for comparasion of 2 pdf documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011432/web-based-application-for-comparasion-of-2-pdf-documents/30452232#30452232)